# Can't find NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a layout constraint which is related with `TopLayoutGuide.bottom` and `CUTableView(subclass of UITableView).bottom`.

[image]

The above screenshot is the properties of the constraint.

[image]

The constraint is on `ImageSelectVC(UIViewController)`'s view.

What I want to do is modifying the constant, so I tried to find the constraint with code as below.

```
for(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_ in self.view.constraints) {
    NSLog(@"%@", constraint_);
}
```

What I've got is...

```
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1702ace40 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7540(0)]>
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1702a7f80 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7540]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170188200 )>
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1702acf00 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7380(0)]>
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1702acea0 _UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7380.bottom == UIView:0x170188200.bottom>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170282710 V:[UICollectionView:0x145054400]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7380]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170282760 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7540]-(12)-[UIButton:0x14454a400]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174492bb0 UIView:0x170188200.centerX == UIButton:0x14454a400.centerX>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174492ed0 H:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x145054400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170188200 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174495540 V:[UIButton:0x14454a400]-(12)-[UICollectionView:0x145054400]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174491170 H:[UICollectionView:0x145054400]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170188200 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174497020 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x170188200(320)]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174496940 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x170188200(504)]>
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174496c10 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x170188200]   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x17418e450 )>
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174496e90 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x170188200]   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x17418e450 )>
```

I linked a IBOutlet to the constraint and printed a log of it.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170282da0 CUTableView:0x1448e9800.bottom == _UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7540.bottom>
```

Apparently it's not on `UIViewController's view`.

Where can I find the `NSLayoutConstraint` of `CUTableView-TopLayoutGuide`?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to "find" it is to do what you did apparently as a diagnostic step: create and connect an outlet for it.

Constraints are added to the common ancestor of the views which it relates (where a view is considered an "ancestor" of itself). Presumably, the constraint has been added to the framework-private view that's the common ancestor of your view and the "Top Layout Guide" (another framework-private view that's logged as `_UILayoutGuide:0x1701a7540`).